# Implementing FromStr for a custom &[u8] type

Tags: rust, lifetime

This is a two-parter.

Ideally I'd like to implement the FromStr trait, but with or without that, I need to implement from_str().

A CqlString consists of a u16 (two u8s) followed by the raw bytes of the original string.

The version below generates "error: 'bytes' does not live long enough", so that's problem #1.
If I make it "impl FromStr for CqlString", then I get an earlier error of:
error: method `from_str` has an incompatible type for trait: expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter  [E0053]

So given the structure of CqlString, how can I implement a FromStr fn properly?

```
#[repr(C, packed)] 
pub struct CqlString<'a>(&'a [u8]);

impl<'a> CqlString<'a>  {
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Option<CqlString> {
        let mut bytes = Vec::<u8>::new();
        bytes.push_all(unsafe{Utils::raw_byte_repr(&s.len().to_u16())}); //convert the hashmap length to a a two byte short and start building our &[u8]
        bytes.push_all(s.as_bytes());
        let cqls = CqlString(bytes[]);
        Some(cqls)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. `CqlString` contains a reference to other data, but `FromStr` expects to create a fully-owned object that no longer needs to reference the `&str`. These two concepts are incompatible.

The closest I can see is that you could create an `OwnedCqlString`:

```
struct OwnedCqlString {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl OwnedCqlString {
    fn as_cql_string(&self) -> CqlString { CqlString(self.data.as_slice()) }
}

impl FromStr for OwnedCqlString {
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Option<OwnedCqlString> {
        // logic here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ocs: OwnedCqlString = "hello".parse();
    let cs = ocs.as_cql_string();
}
```

Ultimately, this comes down to two questions:

1. Where are you going to store the bytes that represent the size?
2. How do you ensure that those bytes immediately precede the string data in memory?

#### An alternate idea

If you didn't need to store the slice of bytes, but instead could have a "streaming" interface, then you could implement that directly on `&str`:

```
trait WriteCqlStr {
    fn write_to<W>(&self, &mut W)
        where W: Writer; 
}

impl WriteCqlStr for CqlStr {
    // Straight-forward impl, write the bytes we refer to
}

impl<'a> WriteCqlStr for &'a str {
    // Write the length, then write the bytes of the str
}
```

Comment: What about a third possibility that I didn't mention. if CqlString is just a newtype for [u8] (no &):
    pub struct CqlString([u8]);
Then I get
    error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `[u8]`
Is that resolvable?

Comment: I honestly don't know what that ends up meaning, but it looks like Dynamically Sized Type (DST) territory.

Comment: Ok, so I think I can use the alternate streaming interface approach, but the trait definition isn't valid in the example you provided. "Use of undeclared type name W".

Comment: Awesome set of answers. Thank you.