# How can I create newtypes for an unsized type and its owned counterpart (like `str` and `String`) in safe Rust?

Tags: rust, newtype

I want to create a pair of newtypes `Tag(str)` and `TagBuf(String)`,
analogous to how `Path` and `PathBuf` wrap `OsStr` and `OsString`. My
end goal is to have a map keyed by `TagBuf` and to be able to index into
it with just a `Tag`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut m: HashMap<TagBuf, i32> = HashMap::new();
    m.insert(TagBuf("x".to_string()), 1);
    assert_eq!(m.get(Tag::new("x")), Some(&1));
}
```

But I’m running into issues because `Tag` is dynamically sized.

Specifically, [implementing `Borrow<Tag> for TagBuf` is tricky:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=911949bc8b10ae7f72527be6aa01a4ba)

```rust
pub struct Tag(str);
pub struct TagBuf(String);

impl std::borrow::Borrow<Tag> for TagBuf {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Tag {
        let s: &str = self.0.as_str();
        // How can I turn `&str` into `&Tag`? A naive attempt fails:
        &Tag(*s)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:10
  |
8 |         &Tag(*s)
  |          ^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: all function arguments must have a statically known size
```

I can just return `unsafe { std::mem::transmute(s) }` with a
`#[repr(transparent)]` annotation, but I would like to avoid unsafe
code.

I’ve looked at the source for `Path`/`PathBuf` and [come up with the
following:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e8d12559b10cf0dfd9b04d85b5ee43a)

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::ops::Deref;

#[repr(transparent)]
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Tag(str);
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash, Clone)]
pub struct TagBuf(String);

impl Tag {
    fn new<S: AsRef<str> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Tag {
        unsafe { &*(s.as_ref() as *const str as *const Tag) }
    }
}

impl Deref for TagBuf {
    type Target = Tag;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Tag {
        Tag::new(&self.0)
    }
}

impl Borrow<Tag> for TagBuf {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Tag {
        self.deref()
    }
}

impl ToOwned for Tag {
    type Owned = TagBuf;
    fn to_owned(&self) -> TagBuf {
        TagBuf(self.0.to_owned())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = std::collections::HashMap::<TagBuf, i32>::new();
    m.insert(TagBuf("x".to_string()), 1);
    assert_eq!(m.get(Tag::new("x")), Some(&1));
}
```

…and this works, and I can understand it (good!), but it still uses
`unsafe` for that cast, which I’d like to avoid.

I saw [the Rustonomicon section on exotically sized types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts), which
*doesn’t* use `unsafe`, but the unsizing coercion seems complicated, and
I don’t see how to adapt it from `[u8]` to `str`, since there’s no
stringy counterpart to `[u8; N]`.

I also read the implementation of `Rc<str>`, which seems to do some more
unsafe conversion via `Rc<[u8]>` and some specialization magic that
I had trouble understanding.

I’ve read some related questions, like:

- [Implementing FromStr for a custom &[u8] type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723433/implementing-fromstr-for-a-custom-u8-type)
- https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-newtype-string/5211

…but I haven’t found an answer.

Does latest stable Rust have a way to define a newtype pair for `str`
and `String` in safe code? If not, are there RFCs or tracking issues
that I should follow?

Comment: I'm not sure you can wrap `str` directly. `&str` is the more common form, probably for this reason.

Comment: AFAIK, you currently do need to use `unsafe` (or a crate that uses `unsafe`) to do this.

Comment: Yeah I'm also curious why you're using `Tag(str)` instead of `Tag<'a>(&'a str)`.

Comment: @PitaJ: It’s a fair question, but how would you implement `Borrow<Tag<?>> for TagBuf`, which is required to use it as a map key? Implementing `impl<'a> Borrow<Tag<'a>> for TagBuf` doesn’t seem right: (a) that would let you get a `&'static str` from a stack-owned `TagBuf`, and (b) you’d need to implement `fn borrow<'a>(&'s self) -> &'s Tag<'a>`, which doesn’t look possible (for good reason).

Comment: `Path::new()` does use unsafe, so it might be required.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Thanks for the references! Both answers in “avoid temporary allocations” incur runtime cost (`Cow<'_, str>`, `&(dyn Key + '_)`). While the FFI question is related and the best _answers_ may end up being similar, the questions are sufficiently different. `str` and `c_void` have quite different meanings and representations (`&str` is a fat pointer; `&c_void` is not), and the lack of an FFI boundary simplifies things quite a lot. A canonical answer to this question would be useful to many more people than an answer to that one, so this question should stand.

Comment: saying `void *` is not a fat pointer is not true, actually it's whatever according to the C standard. it's an opaque type that "can allow other pointer to be cast into it and can do the reverse operation". There is some system where void * is very special.

Comment: @Stargateur: Sure; what I meant is that `std::mem::size_of::<&str>()` is `16` on my system, whereas `std::mem::size_of::<&c_void>()` is `8`.

Comment: Just another FYI about the `new()` implementation required to get `&unsized`s into `Newtype(unsized)`, not the question itself: For anyone else who hates writing boilerplate (and unsafe boilerplate doubly so), the [`opaque_typedef` crate](https://crates.io/crates/opaque_typedef/0.0.5) provides a derive macro to do this part for you (except it's called `from_inner` instead of `new`; it also gives you `as_inner` to get the `&unsized` out of the newtype struct again). Might save some people some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be solved in safe Rust without some small overhead.

This is how I'd solve it using `unsafe`:

```rust
use std::{borrow::Borrow, ops::Deref};

#[repr(transparent)]
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct Tag(str);

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash, Clone)]
pub struct TagBuf(String);

impl Tag {
    fn new<S: AsRef<str> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Tag {
        unsafe { &*(s.as_ref() as *const str as *const Tag) }
    }
}

impl Deref for TagBuf {
    type Target = Tag;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &Tag {
        Tag::new(&self.0)
    }
}

impl Borrow<Tag> for TagBuf {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Tag {
        self.deref()
    }
}

impl ToOwned for Tag {
    type Owned = TagBuf;
    
    fn to_owned(&self) -> TagBuf {
        TagBuf(self.0.to_owned())
    }
}

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m = HashMap::new();
    m.insert(TagBuf("x".to_string()), 1);
    assert_eq!(m.get(Tag::new("x")), Some(&1));
}
```

See also:

- [How do I handle an FFI unsized type that could be owned or borrowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613798/155423)
- [How to wrap a borrowed value in a newtype that is also a borrowed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53999600/155423)
- [How to avoid temporary allocations when using a complex key for a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36480845/155423)
- [How to implement HashMap with two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786717/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes! Glad to see that my code is identical to what you came up with. :-) I’ll accept this, but will happily accept another answer if it becomes possible in safe Rust.

Comment: I tried to apply this approach for a more generic case, but failed - if you have some suggestions to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76873404/using-hashmapstring-with-str-key ?